# Story about parents being controlled, children locked away

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book or story - I remember a decent amount of details but have made no headway searching for it.

The parents (all adults in town?) are being controlled somehow. They lock the kids (a brother and sister?) away in their respective rooms but they cut out the wall in each of their closets to meet each other and communicate to plan. I distinctly remember one of the adults swallowing the key.

The children eventually discover the aliens/monsters have a weakness to wood (wooden crate). They sneak out to where the creatures live or come from - I believe caves. There, the alien/monsters' children are surprised and reveal they don't agree with what their parents are doing. I think they communicate with the kids telepathically, as they are blobs/shadows/tentacles/undeveloped?

I'm pretty sure I read this story before 2001 but it was definitely before 2005. It could be part of a series like Goosebumps or Bruce Coville but if so I haven't narrowed it down.